# Bridge between ActiveMQ and MSMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, msmq, messaging

Let's say there is an ActiveMQ as JMS broker which is fed by a master system based on java.

One of the consumers can work with MSMQ only (and we can do nothing with it)

**Question** Is there an easy way to forward jms text in jms messages in ActiveMQ topic to some message at MSMQ destination?

Underlying jms message contains the text of an xml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends a bit on your preferences, but a simple [Camel route](http://activemq.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) in ActiveMQ dispatching messages to MSMQ can do this easily - GIVEN you run your AMQ on Windows.

Camel does not really support MSMQ, but you can use some [simple java lib](http://msmqjava.codeplex.com/) to dispatch messages inside a java processor.

Comment: so, @Petter, you mean it would be smth like this: `<camelContext     xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring">
      <route>
        <from uri="activemq:com.acme.MyQueue"/>
        <to uri="msmq:com.acme.SomeOtherQueue"/>
      </route>
    </camelContext>` ?

Comment: Well, there is no native msmq support in Camel. There was, but that module is gone. I was thinking a custom bean.

`public class MsmqSenderBean{
    public void send(String text){
        Queue queue= new Queue(fullname);
         String label="testmessage";
         byte[] correlationId = { 0,2,4,6,8,9 }; 
         Message msg= new Message(text, label, correlationId);
         queue.send(msg);
    }
}`

Wire up as a spring bean in camel.xml and call with `<to uri="bean:msmqSenderBean"/>`

You might want to make it more flexible with configurable queue names etc..

Comment: and yes, you need to put a jar with your custom bean in the ActiveMQ lib folder.